О склонении фамилии Потиха
 — Можно ли не склонять фамилию Потиха? —  Нет! 
   Склонение обязательно!
 — Простите, а почему Вы не склоняете фамилию 
   Потиха (который Зиновий Аронович)? 

Признаться, вопрос поставил меня в тупик. Я знаю, что Потиха З.А. — это Зиновий Аронович,  но я как раз хотела отличить его  от Зинаиды Андреевны.

Почему я не склоняю фамилию Потиха? Конечно, я в курсе, что славянские фамилии на безударный А обычно склоняются.  Но я хочу сохранить точность фамилии.  Может, она и славянская, но по фонетике однозначно не скажешь, а в источниках разные  сведения. Точно также никто не говорит в Строгине, хотя нормой считается склонение.

Кроме того, есть еще проблема: парадигма склонения общая для женского и мужского варианта, но это не очень удобно.  К примеру,  мы различаем склонение имен Анны Смит и Адама Смита.  Но там мужской вариант 2-го склонения считается основным и поэтому склоняется.

А для фамилии Потиха основным следует считать женский вариант 1-го склонения, так как одушевлённых существительных мужского рода не так много.  И вот это "женское" склонение звучит не очень корректно.


Но в основном пользователи следуют правилам и фамилию склоняют, хотя в форме Р.п. происходит чередование твердого и мягкого согласного: Потиха — нет Потихи.
И вопрос: Почему склонение считается обязательным, если не различаются женский и мужской варианты этой  фамилии?
Склонение фамилии Потиха по родам, лицам и падежам
